# Ruby on Rails - PUT Method Creates Extra Params Entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, put, restful-architecture

So I observed some weird behaviour while implementing an endpoint for a RESTful API I am creating for a mobile client.  I am using a PUT method to update an attribute on the `User` model.  I send the user's id as a URL parameter and the value to update inside a JSON object.  Everything seems to work just fine but when I check the parameters via the rails logs I noticed something strange.  For some reason there is an extra parameter being sent to the backend that I can't seem to explain.  Here are the logs I am seeing when I call this endpoint from the mobile client:

```
Parameters: {"enable_security"=>true, "id"=>"7d7fec98-afba-4ca9-a102-d5d71e13f6ce", "user"=>{}}
```

As can be seen above an additional `"user"=>{}` is appended to the list of parameter entries.  I see this when I print out the params object as well.  I can't seem to explain where this is coming from.  I also checked the mobile client just to be safe and there is no where in code where I send a parameter with a key `user`.  This is very puzzling to me and makes me think I am missing something fairly simple.  Why is there an empty object with the `user` key being sent to the backend RESTful API?

**Update to Provide More Information**

Here is the code that gets called when the user hits the endpoint that updates the user `User` model:

```
  #PUT /:id/user/update_security_settings
  def update_security_settings
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @user.advanced_security_enabled = params[:enable_security]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        response = {:status => "200", :message => "User's security settings updated."}
        format.json { render json: response, status: :ok }
      else
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Update in Response to User's Comments**

Here are the routes that pertain to the `user_controller`, the view controller that defines all endpoints that deal with creating and updating the `User` model.

```
post '/user/upload_profile', to: 'user#upload_profile'
get '/:id/user', to: 'user#find_user'
put '/:id/user/update_security_settings', to: 'user#update_security_settings'
resources :user, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Comment: Can you post the form from which you are submitting, i beilive there is a User.new there if i am not mistaken.

Comment: There is no form its a RESTFul api.  I can post the code that gets called when the endpoint is hit?  Is that what you meant? @Coderhs

Answer (score 3):

Does this comment really mirror your actual route?

`#PUT /:id/user/update_security_settings`

I'd expect it to be `/user/:id/update_security_settings` instead.

Can you show us your config/routes.rb - My wild guess is that your routes are somehow configured to expect an actual nested user param, which you don't send (of course) and therefor appears empty in the logs.

Update:
Some of your routes are unusual. You actually  don't need the find_user route as it should be covered under `resources :user` as show action (provided you defined a show method in your controller, which is the default way to retrieve a single resource item; so no need for find_user)

For custom routes like your update_security_settings action I'd suggest to stick to the default pattern, like `resource/:id/action`and nesting it in the default resourceful route. Putting the id before the resource is very unusual, confusing and may actually be related to your issue (thoguh I#m not sure about that). Try cleaning up your routes.rb liek this:

```
# notice that resources expects the plural form :users
resources :users do
  member do 
    patch :update_security_settings
    post :upload_profile
    # any other custom routes
  end
end
```

This will result in routes like `GET /users` (index), `GET /users/1` (show) and `PATCH /users/1/update_security_settings`.

More on routing an be found here: [Rails Guides | Routing From The Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Please check if the changes above remove your empty user param.

Comment: Hey @thirdsun I posted the routes associated with the controller in question.  I apologize if my URLs are a bit unconventional I don't have any formal training with Ruby on Rails and am unaware of many common coding conventions and best practices.

Comment: @ScottOBot Thanks, I updated my answer. Again, my guess is that the unusual route design (like :id before user) introduces unexpected/strange params.

Answer (score 1):

Check your configuration in

```
config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
```

`wrap_parameters format: []` this list should not contain json then it will wrap the parameters to the root of you controller for all the json request. Refer [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html) docs